# python grep look for a pattern and then a number of lines before

Tags: python, grep, lines

I'm looking to do the equivalent of `_grep -B14 MMA`

I have a URL that I open and it spits out many lines. 
I want to

1. find the line that has 'MMa'
2. then print the 14th line before it

I don't even know where to begin with this.

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = "https://longannoyingurl.com"

opts = {
  'action': 'Dump+It'
}
data = urllib.urlencode(opts)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print  response.read() # gives the full html output
```

Comment: What is the expected result when more than one line matches?

Comment: How do you not know where to begin? You must have an IDEA of where to begin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of just doing a bare `read` on the response object, call `readlines` instead, and then run a regular expression through each line. If the line matches, print the 14th line before it, but check to see that you're not negative indexing. E.g.

```
import re

lines = response.readlines()

r = re.compile(r'MMa')
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if r.search(lines[i]):
        print lines[max(0, i-14)]
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Dan I got my result

```
import urllib
import urllib2 
import re

url="https://somelongannoyingurl/blah/servlet"
opts = {
  'authid': 'someID',
   'action': 'Dump+It'
}
data = urllib.urlencode(opts)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

lines = response.readlines()
r = re.compile(r'MMa')
for i in range(len(lines)):
  if r.search(lines[i]):
    line = lines[max(0, i-14)].strip()
    junk,mma = line.split('>')
    print mma.strip()
```

~

Answer (score 0):

You can split a single string into a list of lines using [`mystr.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).  You can test if a string matches a regular expression using [`re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match).  Once you find the matching line(s), you can index backwards into your list of lines to find the 14th line before.

Comment: In this situation, `search` is probably a better fit than `match`.